# Using object from other class

Tags: java, android

I have mainActivity class and class1. In class1 i have something like this

```
public void ownedAdd(int a)
{
    owned = owned +a;
}
```

Simple. But when i want to call this method in MainActivity

```
    Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            obj1.ownedAdd(10);
        }
    });
```

And in this place i have few question. Android Studio saying that obj1 need to be declared as final. I dont like that. What i want to do is using class1 object in main method. Is that possible? I want to make few objects of class1 each with some variable as price, owned etc and i have no idea how. For any help, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Why don't you just declare it final?

Comment: "I dont like that." Why not? What don't you like about it? It doesn't help that you haven't shown where the `main` method is, or anything similar...

Comment: Is that a proper way?

Comment: Didnt know something about "final". Thanks

Comment: @Rasta_Man Declaring an object final means the object cannot reference any other object. Something like a constant. Later you cannot execute statements like "obj1 = new Class1()" because it has once been done and declared final. Its not going to harm your purpose in any way. Alternately, you can check the solution I posted. That wil also work without declaring obj1 as final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong is that in JAVA, you cannot access a variable from a method to an anonymous class inside that method unless the variable is declared final inside the method, or the variable is itself global to the parent Class.

To solve your problem, set the `obj1` variable to be global. Something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Declare the obj1 object here
    Class1 obj1;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       //inflate layout and do other stuff

       //from where you posted
       obj1 = new Class1();
       Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

       button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               obj1.ownedAdd(10);
           }
       }); 
   }
}
```

Comment: This isn't "global", it is just a member variable of `MainActivity`. The disadvantage of doing this is that it is in an unnecessarily broad scope - one has to worry about something other than the button click listener changing the value. It is much cleaner just to make the local variable final. Or, for that matter, making it a member variable of the anonymous click listener.

Comment: Well we both know that in JAVA there's nothing called "global", what i meant was that its scope to be the entire class. This answer is an answer to the question posted regarding not using final, I even left a comment stating that "final" object will suit his task equally. And I wouldn't actually agree this being a disadvantage because suppose later he needed to access the objects from other methods then this is the only possible solution other than having to pass the object on every method call.

Comment: If you know it is incorrect terminology, don't use it :) Using a meaningless term can confuse beginners.

Answer (score 0):

From the code given, you don't need the reference to the `Class1` instance other than in the click listener, so you can simply make it a member variable of the `View.OnClickListener`:

```
   button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       final Class1 obj1 = new Class1();

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           obj1.ownedAdd(10);
       }
   });
```

(Although it is still worth making it final).

However, it's not super-useful like that, since only the click listener can access the instance - you can't display the value in another control, for example. It is simplest just to make your current local variable `final`.